# Apache Jackrabbit WebDAV Put xml file successful but download empty file

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit

I'm using Apache Jackrabbit WebDAV, and I'm encountering an issue with the PUT method when uploading XML and ZIP files. The upload appears to be successful, but when I try to download the uploaded XML file, the file is empty. Similarly, when I upload a ZIP file containing an XML file and extract it, the extracted XML file is also empty.

Strangely, I've tried the same procedure with other file types like .docx and .pdf, and they download perfectly fine.